# How to display a control (e.g. TListbox) beyond the borders of a TForm

Tags: delphi, tform, tlistbox

How can I display a Listbox beyond the borders of the parent Form at runtime:

[image]

The image is obtained from the IDE when clicking on the listbox in design time. I would like to achieve this effect at runtime.

Comment: You can't. That's probably a drag image, not the control itself.

Comment: I remember DropDownForm from MustangPeak which implemented ComboBox-like behaviour like you seem to want. Maybe you can take some ideas from it **if** you manage to find a copy.

Comment: You mean to achieve the same effect whilst dragging the control at runtime or keep it displayed this way?

Comment: You'll need it to be its own form.

Comment: @Uli and Jerry: Thanks, that gives me an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Hence my comment. Either you want a drag image or come kind of popup form.

Comment: @Victoria: I mentioned dragging only because that is how I managed to get this picture, but it is not what I want.I want to achieve a popup form/list.

Comment: My confusion arised from your sentence "I would like to achieve **this effect** at runtime". I thought you want to drag the controls the same way the IDE form designer does.

Comment: Down voted... Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not really visually extend the control outside of the parent form. But you can achieve the effect by creating a separate borderless form for this control and display this secondary form partly over the first form:

[image]

Here `Form1` is a main form, with following `OnClick` handler for `Button1`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    Form2.Left := ClientOrigin.X + 140;
    Form2.Top := ClientOrigin.Y + ClientHeight - 20;
    Form2.ShowModal;
    Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Form2.ModalResult);
  finally
    Form2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Since the second form (`Form2`) is not related (child - parent wise) to `Form1` we must give its location as screen pixels, but still relative to `Form1`. Therefore we use the `Form1.ClientOrigin` (`Form1 client area top and left as screen coordinates) as reference.

The second form, `Form2` that holds the `TListBox`, has following property settings

```
BorderStyle = bsNone
KeyPreview = True (to catch `Enter` key)
```

and it has the `OnKeyUp` event handler written as

```
procedure TForm2.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
    ModalResult := ListBox1.ItemIndex;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. For my purposes, it is better to call `Form2.Show` (not modal), and set `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop`. If Form2 is ShowModal then Form1 is completely inaccessible, which is not the idea of having a "Listbox on a Form"

Comment: I understand your viewpoint, but then you also need to decide how to deal with user moving form1, or minimizing / maximizing or just resizing it. I'm not saying it is not doable, but ...